# How to Outline stroke included appearance panel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, appearance

[image]

Hello. I'm an illustrator in Korea.

I have one question.

How to outline stroke to stroke in appearance panel?

(now.. If I create outline to type still on stroke option not change to path.)

I have check all option about this but I can't.

there's are anybody know about this problem?

thank you...

Answer (score 3):

`Object > Expand Appearance` -- this will covert the Appearance items to actual objects.

Then if you want the stroke outlined choose `Object > Expand`.

Although, if you merely click **Scale Strokes and Effects** on the **Transform Panel** (Window > Transform) with the object selected, the appearance strokes will scale with the object.

[image]